# Is it possible to lose Insight?

Tags: bloodborne

As I've progressed through the game, I've been steadily gaining Insight via fighting bosses and Madman's Knowledge items. Ultimately, I'm interested in seeing what I can buy with Insight from the Insight shop in the Hunter's Dream, but I haven't gained access to it quite yet, so for the moment I have a decently-sized Insight pool just sitting on my character.

Unlike Humanity in Dark Souls, I don't seem to lose any Insight when I die in Bloodborne, which is nice, but I still feel a little nervous about having an active Insight count on the HUD, as though it might be possible to lose them somehow, such as through PvP or something like that. I know that you can *spend* Insight to summon other players for co-op play, but I'm only concerned about whether it can be "taken" or "lost" somehow.

Do I have anything to worry about, or can I consider my Insight to be safely "banked" until I'm ready to use it?

If my Insight *is* safe, is there any reason not to immediately use all future Madman's Knowledge items when I obtain them, rather than keep them in item form until they're needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't ever lose it from dying, some enemies steal it. A couple areas are harder if you have 15 or more. It's pretty easy to get if you just want to spend it though.

Answer (score 3):

There is an enemy in the area below the Cathedral, which becomes accessible after the Blood-Starved Beast boss, that is very reminiscent of the guards in Latria's Tower in Demon's Souls. It has a paralyzing attack and then sucks two insight out of you per attack.

Answer (score -2):

unfortunately you will lose insight later in the game if u are dying, my experience from 17 insight i die 3 time then realize my insight drop to 3.
Just keep MMK and spend your current insight.

Comment: Are you sure about this? According to the wiki it's not possible to lose insight upon dying, only the Brainsuckers can do that: http://bloodborne.wikia.com/wiki/Insight